# Add vertical spacing between fields on VerticalFieldManager

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I am adding fields to a VerticalFieldManager. Is there a method of adding vertical spacing between fields?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are more elogant ways of doing this using the `setPositionChild()` methods but a simple work around is to give your fields padding using the [setPadding(int top, int right, int bottom, int left)](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Field.html#setPadding%28int,int,int,int%29) method.

```
myField.setPadding(5, 0, 5, 0);
```

Answer (score 6):

There's several solutions to this, one being that you can create a custom field to be used as a spacer between your other fields.

```
private static class SpacerField extends Field
{
    private int spacerWidth;
    private int spacerHeight;
    private SpacerField(int width, int height) {
        spacerWidth = width;
        spacerHeight = height;
    }

    protected void layout(int width, int height) {
        setExtent(getPreferredWidth(), getPreferredHeight());
    }

    protected void paint(Graphics g) {
        // nothing to paint; this is a blank field
    }

    public int getPreferredHeight() {
        return spacerHeight;
    }

    public int getPreferredWidth() {
        return spacerWidth;
    }
}

//...
// Usage

add(new LabelField("Before Spacer"));
add(new SpacerField(0, 100));
add(new LabelField("After Spacer"));
```

Setting the padding or margins of your contained fields is another solution. It's up to you on what you think is the best way of managing things.

Comment: Are there any performance differences between adding fields and adding spacing?

Answer (score 1):

I actually find that most times, what you want to do is call `setMargin()` on the vertical field manager's child fields, **not** `sePadding()`.  I certainly think [creating a SpacerField](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5092480/119114) is now unnecessarily complex.

```
myField.setMargin(5, 0, 5, 0);
```

It depends on which kind of child field we're talking about, and how its size is specified, but in general, `setPadding()` will actually make the field bigger, which could have a visual impact, depending on how the field's background and border are drawn.  `setMargin()` does not make the field any bigger, which I think is more consistent with what the question is asking.

[See Mr Vincenzo's answer here, with pictures!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9812241/119114)

**Note:** `setMargin()` and `setPadding()` were officially added to the `Field` API relatively late in the BlackBerry Java evolution, but were available as undocumented methods before that.

**Another Note:** I have seen strange problems when using `setMargin()`, like the [one described in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14909419/119114).  In that case, I did have to resort to one of the other two solutions here.

Comment: Setting the margin seems to be 'safer' than setting the padding as well. Some versions of BBOS don't react well when setting padding on a NullField, for example.  Also, +1 for SpacerField being unnecessary for BlackBerry these days.  NullField is useful for absorbing the focus though, if you want to allow focus to move off of an element when nothing else will receive the focus on the screen.