# Blackberry field padding

Tags: user-interface, blackberry, field

I'm trying to pad an email field with the following snippet:

```
    emailField = new BasicEditField(BasicEditField.FILTER_EMAIL|Field.FIELD_HCENTER|TextField.NO_NEWLINE|Field.HIGHLIGHT_FOCUS|Field.FOCUSABLE);
    emailField.setLabel("Email: ");
    emailField.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
    emailField.setBorder(BorderFactory.createRoundedBorder(new XYEdges(10, 10, 10, 10), 0x0083B0D7, Border.STYLE_SOLID));
```

[image]

Is there a proper way to pad such that there appears no margin between the border and the field background?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Image attachement fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `setMargin(5,5,5,5)` instead of `setPadding(5,5,5,5)`.

> [Field#setMargin()](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Field.html#setMargin%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)
> Margin is the area outside a field, after the border. It is up to a manager to allocate margins properly since these overlap.
>
> [Field#setPadding()](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Field.html#setPadding%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)
> Padding is the area within a field between the content and the border.
>
> [Field#SetBorder()](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Field.html#setBorder%28net.rim.device.api.ui.decor.Border%29)
> The border is the area within a field outside the padding and before the margin.

[image]

**UPDATE**:
Your are right, replacing `setPadding()` with `setMargin()` only, didn't produced the desired result. The reason is the `Border` you are using, to be more precise its thickness (**10**) and style (**STYLE_SOLID**). Decrease the border thickness to **3** and change it style to **STYLE_FILLED**.

After the aforementioned changes
[image]

And now the code snippet:

```
public class PlayingWithBorders extends MainScreen {
    public PlayingWithBorders() {
        super(NO_VERTICAL_SCROLL | NO_HORIZONTAL_SCROLL | USE_ALL_HEIGHT | USE_ALL_WIDTH);

        VerticalFieldManager vfm = new VerticalFieldManager(USE_ALL_HEIGHT | USE_ALL_WIDTH);
        vfm.setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createSolidBackground(Color.CYAN));
        
        BasicEditField emailField = new BasicEditField();
        emailField.setLabel("Email: ");
        emailField.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        emailField.setMargin(5, 5, 5, 5);
        emailField.setBorder(BorderFactory.createRoundedBorder(new XYEdges(3, 3, 3, 3), 0x0083B0D7, Border.STYLE_FILLED));
        emailField.setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createSolidBackground(Color.WHITE));

        BasicEditField passwordField = new BasicEditField();
        passwordField.setLabel("Password: ");
        passwordField.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        passwordField.setMargin(5, 5, 5, 5);
        passwordField.setBorder(BorderFactory.createRoundedBorder(new XYEdges(3, 3, 3, 3), 0x0083B0D7, Border.STYLE_FILLED));
        passwordField.setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createSolidBackground(Color.WHITE));
        
        vfm.add(emailField);
        vfm.add(passwordField);
        add(vfm);
    }
```

Comment: Still the same. Didn't change.