# setMargin and setPadding blackberry API

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator

I have been trying some UI stuff on BB devices and I'm a bit confused between setMargin and setPadding functions of the Field class. I know their definitions but I dont get when I'm supposed to use either of one for any field. 
Any help, examples would be highly appreciated!

Thanks!!

Comment: Check my answer to *Blackberry field padding question*, http://stackoverflow.com/a/9812241/396949.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Difference between `setMargin()` and `setPadding()` will be clear by the fig. below

[image]
`setMargin()` sets the margin of one field from the other field as shown in fig.1

and `setPadding()` increasse the area of the field on which you are setting the padding. As shown in fig.2 the extent of **Button2** become increased, while in `setMargin()`, the *extent* of field remains same and the spacing between the field become changed.