# Layout design issue with alignment blackberry

Tags: java, blackberry

i am developing an application in which i need to set two button in `HorizontalFieldManage`. where one `Bitmap` should stay left and another `LabelField` should stay center at horizontally. here i have tried many time but cant able to set first `Bitmap` at Left so can you please help me out from this..

**Here is my Code ::**

```
VerticalFieldManager VFM = new VerticalFieldManager(USE_ALL_WIDTH){
            public void paint(Graphics g) {
                g.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                g.clear();
                super.paint(g);
            }
        };
        HorizontalFieldManager HFM = new HorizontalFieldManager(FIELD_HCENTER){
            public void paint(Graphics g) {
                g.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                g.clear();
                super.paint(g);
            }
        };

        Bitmap logom1;
        logom1 = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("logo48X48.png");
        BitmapField imgField = new BitmapField(logom1,Field.FIELD_LEFT);
        LabelField RegistrationLbl = new LabelField("Registration",FIELD_HCENTER | FIELD_BOTTOM);

        FontFamily fontFamily[] = FontFamily.getFontFamilies();
        Font font = fontFamily[1].getFont(FontFamily.CBTF_FONT, 20);
        font = fontFamily[1].getFont(Font.BOLD, 25);
        RegistrationLbl.setFont(font);

        HFM.add(imgField);
        HFM.add(RegistrationLbl);

        VFM.add(HFM);
        add(VFM);
```

Comment: Post a sketch or image of the layout you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this (This is not a correct way)-

```
        HorizontalFieldManager VFM = new HorizontalFieldManager(){
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.clear();
        super.paint(g);
        }
        };

        HorizontalFieldManager LogoHFM = new HorizontalFieldManager(FIELD_LEFT);
        Bitmap logom1;
        logom1 = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("logo48X48.png");
        BitmapField imgField = new BitmapField(logom1);
        LogoHFM.add(imgField);


        LabelField RegistrationLbl = new LabelField("Registration",FIELD_HCENTER);
        FontFamily fontFamily[] = FontFamily.getFontFamilies();
        Font font = fontFamily[1].getFont(FontFamily.CBTF_FONT, 20);
        font = fontFamily[1].getFont(Font.BOLD, 25);
        RegistrationLbl.setFont(font);
        RegistrationLbl.setMargin(0,0,0,(Display.getWidth()-logom1.getWidth())/4);


        VFM.add(LogoHFM);
        VFM.add(RegistrationLbl);
        add(VFM);
```

Comment: `Display.getWidth()-logom1.getWidth())/4` - how this piece of code can position a field horizontally centred? This is even not considering the width of the `RegistrationLbl`. Position of the `RegistrationLbl` is dependent on it's width.

Answer (score 3):

Signare's general solution could work, but the left margin wasn't quite right.  The only calls you need to add are these (split into two lines for clarity), before adding your label to the `HFM` object:

```java
int labelX = (Display.getWidth() - RegistrationLbl.getPreferredWidth()) / 2;
RegistrationLbl.setMargin(0, 0, 0, labelX - imgField.getPreferredWidth());
```

This assumes the class (`Manager`) that this is in takes up the full screen width (`Display.getWidth()`).

[Read this for a good description of what margin is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9812241/119114).

Also, note that `setMargin()` was undocumented in the APIs before 6.0, but I believe it was actually available (but, undocumented) back to OS 4.5 or so.

**Edit:** by the way, you are assigning your `font` object, and then immediately assigning it to something else. That doesn't look right either, although it doesn't affect the problem centering the label.

**Another Edit:** as illustrated by Rupak's comment, this code only works if you have a fixed orientation display.  If the label is supposed to center itself again on device orientation change, then you need more than this.  Please just add more clarification to the question, if that's needed, and someone will help!

Comment: I think the approach isn't good, because in case of screen orientation change you need to change margin settings. Using a custom FieldManger which manages layout and position of it's child field on it's layout method seems to be perfect for this sort of job.

Comment: @Rupak, he didn't say anything about rotation support (yet).  You're right ...  **if** he needs that, then `setMargin()` alone won't do it.  But, then you can't use a plain `HorizontalFieldManager`, and he probably needs to implement his own `Manager` subclass.  Signare's answer was an improvement on the poster's original implementation, and mine was an improvement on Signare's.  But, I don't want to solve a problem that the poster hasn't identified even exists.

Comment: @Nate, I know that your answer was an improvement of the previously posted one, but I think you are partially biased by the previous answer. Because you assumed that the manager containing the contents are going to added directly on the Screen. What if the manager needs to be placed on other manager. For those cases, I think implementing a custom Manager is the only acceptable solution which takes care of available spaces available to it. And I believe that, when you solve a problem you always take care of the cases that can effect your solution unless you get specific instruction.

Comment: And one more thing, I didn't mean that your approach isn't good on the line `I think the approach isn't good`, but the answer you referred :). Because, first line of the previous answer was, `try this (This is not a correct way)-` - and I was confused about that line.

Comment: @Rupak i know my answer is not correct. thats why i stated that its not a good way. i this my answer is the shortest way to the problem, thats why i put the answer. i know there are problems in screen orientation, thats why i added the comment.

Comment: @Signare, actually I was trying to say only that writing a Custom Manager is the good way to solve this types of tasks. And Nate and you (I was confused about the text on the first line of your answer) also mentioned that. I commented on your answer because calculation of the left margin of the LabelField was wrong, which was fixed later on this post.