# Strange things happen when set margin to VerticalFieldManager

Tags: blackberry

I'd like to generate a `VerticalFieldManager` that has a none-zero margin, so I create a  `VerticalFieldManager`, and then use vfm.setMargin(10, 10, 10, 10); after that, put some fields(`buttonField`, `ObjectChoiceField`) in it.

It seems too simple, right? but strange thing happens. When I focus to the last `ObjectChoiceField` and press space to toggle choice of it, the `ObjectChoiceField` disappeared.

How can that be? here is the demo code, anyone kindly find the bug?

```java
final class HelloWorldScreen extends MainScreen{
  HelloWorldScreen() {
    // just a demo to show the strange thing
    String [] arr = {"a","b"};
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){

        VerticalFieldManager vfm = new VerticalFieldManager(); // Field.USE_ALL_WIDTH
        vfm.setMargin(10, 10, 10, 10);
        ButtonField btn = new ButtonField(String.valueOf(i));
        ObjectChoiceField ch = new ObjectChoiceField(String.valueOf(i), arr);

        vfm.add(btn);
        vfm.add(ch);

        add(vfm);
    }
  }
}
```

**Edit:** screenshot of desired UI margins:

[image]

Comment: +1 for a small, self-contained example, reproducing your problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is strange.

For the benefit of those who don't run your code, what's happening is that when you click on the object choice fields, the whole screen is scrolling a little bit vertically.  After each vertical scroll, the screen loses the ability to scroll all the way down to the bottom.  After many such operations, eventually much of the lower part of this screen is no longer accessible.

**I don't know why this is happening.** (looks like a BlackBerry bug to me)

What I observed is that if you take out the call to

```java
    vfm.setMargin(10, 10, 10, 10);
```

the problem goes away.

May I suggest a workaround where you use

```java
    vfm.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
```

instead?

I know that *margin* and *padding* are not the same thing.  However, depending on what your full UI design is (which I cannot see), *in this case*, setting a 10 pixel padding may be sufficient to do what you were trying to do.

---

**Update:** based on the screenshot of your desired UI, I was able to produce that with this workaround.  Again, it *shouldn't* be this much work, but this additional code worked for me:

```java
public class BugScreen extends MainScreen {

   private static final int BG_COLOR = Color.LIGHTGRAY;
   private static final int FG_COLOR = Color.WHITE;
   private static final int BORDER_LINE_COLOR = Color.GRAY;
   private static final int PAD = 10;

   public BugScreen() {
      super(MainScreen.VERTICAL_SCROLL | MainScreen.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR);

      getMainManager().setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createSolidBackground(BG_COLOR));
      // this additional call ensures that when scrolling bounces, the area "behind"
      // the normal visible area is ALSO of BG_COLOR
      setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createSolidBackground(BG_COLOR));

      // this will establish a thin gray padding on the screen's left/right sides
      // NOTE: I seem to get drawing artifacts if I try to use this for ALL sides!
      getMainManager().setPadding(0, PAD, 0, PAD);

      String [] arr = {"a","b"};
      for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){

         VerticalFieldManager vfm = new VerticalFieldManager(Field.USE_ALL_WIDTH) {
            public int getPreferredWidth() {
               return Display.getWidth() - 2 * PAD;
            }
            public void paint(Graphics graphics) {
               int oldColor = graphics.getColor();
               super.paint(graphics);
               graphics.setColor(BORDER_LINE_COLOR);
               // draw the (1-pixel wide) border size you would like.
               graphics.drawRect(0, 0, getPreferredWidth(), getHeight());
               graphics.setColor(oldColor);
            }
         };

         vfm.setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createSolidBackground(FG_COLOR));
         ButtonField btn = new ButtonField(String.valueOf(i));
         ObjectChoiceField ch = new ObjectChoiceField(String.valueOf(i), arr);

         vfm.add(btn);
         vfm.add(ch);

         // add a separator field to get thin gray margin between (vfm) fields         
         add(new MarginField());

         add(vfm);
      }

      // add one last margin field at the bottom
      add(new MarginField());
   }

   private class MarginField extends Field {
      public MarginField() {
         super(Field.USE_ALL_WIDTH);
      }
      public int getPreferredHeight() { return PAD; }
      protected void paint(Graphics g) {
         int oldColor = g.getColor();
         g.setColor(BG_COLOR);
         g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getPreferredHeight());
         g.setColor(oldColor);
      }
      protected void layout(int width, int height) {
         setExtent(width, getPreferredHeight());               
      }     
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi Nate, it's so kind of you to try and describe the problem so detailed. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi Nate, it's so kind of you to try and describe the problem so detailed. Thanks a lot!  (sorry, I don't know how to begin a new line) Well, I use that code just because I want to make UI like this, http://www.pocketberry.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/video-options-os-7-1.jpg . can you see there are narrow and gray magins for "Features" and "Storage"? at first I think it's simple, just use a verticalfieldmanager and setmargin to it. but it came out i'm wrong. Maybe someone have better ideas to do that?

Comment: thank you, i've tried your solution and it works good. based on that, a new idea came in my mind, the following code can worked for me, and looks a bit simple:

Comment: for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
   VerticalFieldManager vfmOuter = new VerticalFieldManager();
   
    VerticalFieldManager vfmInner = new VerticalFieldManager(); // Field.USE_ALL_WIDTH
    vfmInner.setMargin(5, 10, 5, 10);
    vfmInner.setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createSolidBackground(Color.LIGHTGRAY));
    
    ButtonField btn = new ButtonField(String.valueOf(i));
    ObjectChoiceField ch = new ObjectChoiceField(String.valueOf(i), arr);
    
    vfmInner.add(btn);
    vfmInner.add(ch);
   
   vfmOuter.add(vfmInner);
   add(vfmOuter);
  }